# Why is there an RecussionError here when each function is terminating immediately?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures

```
num=0
def add(n):
    global num
    num+=n
    if n==0:
        return num
    else:
        return add(n-1)

print(add(10000))
```

My understanding is that for each function call, it returns another function (recursion) and  the function which calls "dies" because it has "return"ed something. So there shouldn't be a problem of stack overflow.

But clearly I'm wrong. Where am I wrong?

> ```
> output
>     if n==0:
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
> ```

Thank u!

P.S. I know i'd be better off looping for this problem but i just want to understand the concept.

Comment: Your understanding of how recursion works at a stack level may need some brushing up. It doesn't "die" until it gets popped from the call stack, which in this case occurs after all 10000 calls. There's a limit to how many elements can be on the stack, which is what is causing your error. Your function doesn't fully `return` until the recursed method finishes calling, but that method doesn't finish returning until *its* recursed method call finishes, and so on

Comment: What you are describing as "it returns another function (recursion) and the function which calls "dies"" is called [Tail Call Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), something that no contemporary Python implementation does.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum recursion depth in Python, and how to increase it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The act of "returning a call" as in `return add(n-1)` is commonly known as a [Tail Call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). Semantically the *result* of call is returned, not the call itself. Strict evaluation requires the complete evaluation of the call *while the outer call still lives* before returning the result. Thus, the function is indeed a nested call of depth `n`.

This can be shown by forcing a traceback instead of returning a value. As the final call raises, the outer calls still exist:

```py
>>> def trace(n):
...    if n <= 0:
...        raise LookupError("Showing the traceback/callstack")
...    else:
...        return trace(n-1)
... 
>>> trace(2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 8, in <module>
    trace(2)
  File "...", line 5, in trace
    return trace(n-1)
  File "...", line 5, in trace
    return trace(n-1)
  File "...", line 3, in trace
    raise LookupError("Showing the traceback/callstack")
LookupError: Showing the traceback/callstack
```

---

The optimisation of moving this tail call out of the currently executing call is known as Tail Call Elimination. [The reference implementation CPython does explicitly not perform Tail Call Elimination to avoid losing traceback information.](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2009/04/tail-recursion-elimination.html)

Answer (score 0):

This function actually works, it's just that Python stops the program when you exceed a certain recursion limit (about 1000 recursive calls or so). If you test this program with smaller numbers, everything is fine

Answer (score 0):

Python's default recursion limit is 1000. The limit exists because allowing recursion to occur more than 1000 times doesn't exactly make for lightweight code.
Check how is the limit of recursion

```
import sys
print(sys.getrecursionlimit())
```

Output

```
1000
```

Your function works well for the less number. I have checked it to the last of 997.

and change the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit`:

```
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
```

But doing so is dangerous -- the standard limit is a little conservative, but Python stack frames can be quite big.

Python isn't a functional language and tail recursion is not a particularly efficient technique
You can go through more details about increasing the [limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45869066/recursion-limit-with-python)
Also can get the dept of [maximum recursion depth in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323001/what-is-the-maximum-recursion-depth-in-python-and-how-to-increase-it)

Answer (score 0):

If you pass on such a big number(i.e 10000), the function is told to return the `add(n-1)` if the argument passed to function isn't 0. So it just loops for 10000 times which raises the `RecursionError`, though if you pass a smaller number(lets say 10) then the Error will no longer be generated.